# Does WebMango support uploading DICOM images?

Tags: dicom

I am confused about uploading new DICOM images to webMango. I was able to do it in the desktop version, but I am unable to do it in webMango? Is it possible using WebMango to view a DICOM image? OR not?

Is it always that I have to provide the params ?
Kindly advice.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can view DICOM images in [webMango](http://rii.uthscsa.edu/mango/webmango.html).  You configure it similar to Papaya, except that you need to put double-quotes around the parameter values.  (Also note the `images` array contains another array of DICOM series URLs.) Here's an example:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>webMango</title>
        <script src="mango.js"></script>
        <script src="https://www.java.com/js/deployJava.js"></script>

        <script>        
            var params = [];
            params["images"] = "[['data/volume/brain_001.dcm', 'data/volume/brain_002.dcm', 'data/volume/brain_003.dcm']]";
            params["atlas"] = "data/Talairach.xml";
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <p>This is an example use of webMango.</p>
        <div style="width:800px;" class="mango"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

webMango cannot see the local filesystem.  So you can only load files via URL references in the `params` variable.  I think it would be technically possible to allow it to see the local filesystem (at least on some platforms), but browsers have been dropping support for Java applets in recent years, putting up more and more hurdles.  I'd recommend Papaya over webMango in most cases.

Comment: webMango has feature for ROI which papaya does not support yet. I need the ROI for my application.

Comment: Papaya doesn't yet support ROIs, but you can make an overlay look like an ROI with a custom color table.  See: http://rii.uthscsa.edu/mango/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=447&sid=ccc01bf68e961e012250c78da5ec3097

Comment: It would require code changes and webMango is not open-source.  I'm not sure if this will help, but the desktop version of Mango registers a custom protocol on Windows and OS X.  You can put links on a web page (e.g., mango://myfile) and it will open it in Mango.  http://rii.uthscsa.edu/mango/custom_protocol_spec.html